# DropdownMenuItem exception occured in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

The following message points to the DropdownButton widget. Please help:

"Exception has occurred.
_AssertionError ('package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart': Failed assertion: line 882 pos 15: 'items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null ||
items.where((DropdownMenuItem item) {
return item.value == value;
}).length == 1': There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: 2.
Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value)"

---

ListTile(

title: DropdownButton(

setter.map(function).toList(),

```
                    items: _priorities.map((String dropdownStringItem) {

                      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: dropdownStringItem,
                        child: Text(dropdownStringItem),
                      );
                   
                    }).toList(),
                  
                    style: textStyle,
                  
                    value: getPriorityAsString(note.priority),
                  
                   
                    onChanged: (valueSelectedByUser) => setState(() {
                          updatePriorityAsInt(valueSelectedByUser);
                          debugPrint('User selected $valueSelectedByUser');
                        })),
              ),
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72683345/dropdownmenuitem-exception-occured-in-flutter

Answer (score 0):

this is because the string in your default dropdownValue is not contained in the list of your dropdown menu.

something like,

```
    var val = ['a','b','c'];
    DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
    items: val.map((String value) {
    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
      child: Text(value),
      value: value, 
    );
  }).toList(),
              
  value: 'a' // this is must   
),
```

but if you don't want default value

```
String? value;
DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
                  value: value,
                  hint: Text(
                    'None',
                  ),
```

Comment: Thanks. But what should I exactly amend my set of code?

Comment: this getPriorityAsString(note.priority) value should be one of the priorities array element